# Spring boot @RequestParam unix timestamp to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unix-timestamp

Let's say I have in my RestController

```
@GetMapping("/")
public list(@RequestParam LocalDateTime date) {
}
```

and I make a GET request with date request param as unix timestamp like this:

`http://myserver.com/?date=1504036215944`

How do I make Spring Boot and jackson to use the correct conversion from unix timestamp to LocalDateTime automatically without manually doing the conversion.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestparam

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ it's not duplicate, it's related to SpringBoot and not Spring

Comment: @danial issue solved ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public @ResponseBody String list(TimestampRequestParam date) {
    return date.toString();
}
```

Implementing the time stamp to date converter in setDate

pay attention that the getter & setter must have the parameter name ( the class member can have different name )

```
class TimestampRequestParam {

    private Date date; // member name doesn't need to be like request parameter

    private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

    public Timestamp2DateExample() { }

    // must have the same name as the request param
    public Date getDate() { 
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param timestamp
     * here we convert timestamp to Date, method name must be same as request parameter
     */
    public void setDate(String timestamp) {
        long longParse = Long.parseLong(timestamp);
        this.date = new Date(longParse);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "timestamp2date : " + FORMAT.format(date);
    }

}
```

Output example (pay attention to the port, you might configured differently)

```
$ curl localhost:8080?date=1504036215944

timestamp2date : 2017-08-29 22:50:15.944
```